# Send mail on the command line using nonstandard port

Tags: linux, shell, mailx, mailcatcher

I'm using [MailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/), which listens on port 1025 instead of port 25. I'd like to send an email using `mailx`, e.g.,

```
mailx -s 'Hello World!' foo@example.com
```

How do I get mailx to use the mailcatcher port 1025? The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx) is pretty daunting.

Answer (score -1):

mailx has a system-wide configuration `/etc/mail.rc`.

You can edit the file to add or update the following to set the SMTP server address and port.

```
set smtp=your_mail_server_name_or_IP:port
```

If your mailx command is being run from the same machine as MailCatcher then you can enter:

```
set smtp=localhost:1025
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this gives a deprecated warning and does not work